# earcut.js triangulation with holes

Tags: javascript, canvas, geometry, triangulation, polygons

I'm attempting to do some triangulation using the earcut library. I find the documentation on this library very thin, so hopefully someone has experience with the library and can help me out with this.

What I'm trying to achieve is to triangulate a polygon with an inner polygon which I  want to threat as a hole. For this example I have a simple square polygon, and a smaller square polygon inside it.

The way I understood the earcut input format would handle it by using this array:

```
var a = [
    [[0,100],[100,100],[100,0],[0,0]], //outer polygon
    [[25,25],[75,25],[75,75],[25,75]] //hole
]
var toProcess = earcut.flatten(a);
var result = earcut(toProcess.vertices, toProcess.holes, toProcess.dimensions);
```

It all works and I get some triangles, but I would not expect them to cross the inner polygon.
When drawing the triangles returned on a canvas, this is my result:
[image: drawing polygon on canvas]

I've tried googling a lot and did not find any good examples, also looked through earcuts tests on github, but wheren't able to get much from them either.

The example is pretty basic, so I guess someone with knowledge to this library would probably see what I'm doing wrong immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the github page it takes flat arrays so to get the triangulation for your example, with the second array pointing to the holes, all the verts from the first index of the second array to the end is the hole

```
var v = [[[0,100],[100,100],[100,0],[0,0]], //outer polygon
[[25,25],[75,25],[75,75],[25,75]]],
```

becomes

```
var flat =     [0,100,100,100,100,0,0,0,25,25,75,25,75,75,25,75]
                |     |        |    |   |     |     |     |
// vert index   0     1        2    3   4     5     6     7
```

Verts index is array index / dimensions (2d dimensions = 2)

then the call

```
var poly = earcut(flat,[4]); //points to the hole starting at the 4th vert to the 7th
```

For two holes

```
var flat =     [0,100,100,100,100,0,0,0,25,25,75,25,75,75,25,75, 2,2,7,2,7,7,2,7]
var poly = earcut(flat,[4,8]); // creates two holes 
                               // using verts 4,5,6,7 first hole
                               // uning verts 8,9,10,11 second hole
```

UPDATE

I think the problem is when you draw the polys you are getting the indexes incorrect.

To draw the polys

```
var v = toProcess.vertices
for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i += 3){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(v[result[i]*2],v[result[i]*2+1])
    ctx.lineTo(v[result[i+1]*2],v[result[i+1]*2+1])
    ctx.lineTo(v[result[i+2]*2],v[result[i+2]*2+1])
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using the earcut.flatten function, which produces a flat array with all the vertices, and a second array containing the holes which in my case becomes [4]

Comment: Hi, no I'm sorry it doesn't work, As far as I understand my results the triangles go straight through the inner polygon like in the picture above and that is not what I wanted.

Comment: @Tommy Think I know where you are going wrong. Updated the answer to show how to index the polygons that are returned.

Comment: Thanks, that worked much better. I didn't realize I had to multiply the indexes by 2 I where just drawing like v[result[i]], v[result[i]+1]
Well spotted!!